# Agent is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, nodejs, https

Estoy intentando usar https.Agent pero me da el siguiente error:

```
There was an error invoking the function - https__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Agent is not a constructor
```

Lo único que se me ocurre es que no carga el modulo https de node, lo que no entiendo es por qué

Así hago el import:

```
import { Agent } from 'https';
```

y así intento usar el Agent:

```
agent: new Agent({ ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

No lo he usado nunca, pero una vista rápida en Google me dice que el `import` para NodeJS seria:

```js
var https = require('https');
```

Y el uso:

```js
var agent = new https.Agent({ ... })
```